# beautiful soup parse published date of article on medium python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to parse "published date" of article on medium using beautiful soup.
I successfully parsed in loop author, title, reading time, but for some reason "published date" is not working for me.

here is example:

```
https://medium.com/interlay/archive/2020
```

so output of prasing will be `Jun 18, 2020 ; Mar 5 , 2020 ; Feb 23, 2020 etc.`

Comment: from what i see it should be easy to achieve. how are you proceeding?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Date is present inside the `<time>` tag of every article `<div>`.

Select that `<time>` tag and print it's text.

Here is the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://medium.com/interlay/archive/2020'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

t = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('time')]
print(t)
```

```
['Jun 18, 2020', 'Mar 4, 2020', 'Feb 23, 2020', 'Nov 30, 2020', 'Apr 15, 2020', 'Aug 21, 2020', 'Oct 27, 2020']
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get also year?

Comment: The date has year as well. Please check!

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url='https://medium.com/interlay/archive/2020'
    
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

You can find `main_div` tag as from its class and loop over it to get data from `time` tag

```
main_div=soup.find_all("div",class_="streamItem streamItem--postPreview js-streamItem")
for div in main_div:
    print(div.find("time").text)
```

Output:

```
Jun 18, 2020
Mar 4, 2020
Feb 23, 2020
Nov 30, 2020
Apr 15, 2020
Aug 21, 2020
Oct 27, 2020
```

​